# What type of vessel should be used for boiling water?

Tags: ayurveda

I want to cook "Ushna Udaka" , i.e boiled water. Most websites i find on googling mention "Stainless Steel" vessels. But i doubt stainless steel existed in the older days.

Looking for genuine answers, preferably with citations...

Namaskara !

Comment: Shouldn't it be Copper? That's what people used earlier.

Comment: Also, glazed pottery, unglazed pottery, wood, woven, iron, bronze, copper, stone, and shell, etc vessels, and heating stones could have been available, depending on area and time. And gold and silver would have been scarce. Thank you  :)

Comment: Unfortunately cannot close this question. It is not about Hindu religion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda "Ushna Udaka" is mentioned in Ayurveda.